# How do I make my data template file recognise a number in terraform

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

THe problem I am facing now is this. I am trying to make my policy more flexible. So I shifted them into a file instead of using EOF.

How to make the template file recognise a number value?

`"${max_untagged_images}"` and `"${max_tagged_images}"` are suppose to be numbers.

Aws lifecycle policy:

```
resource "aws_ecr_lifecycle_policy" "lifecycle" {
  count      = length(aws_ecr_repository.repo)
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.repo[count.index].name

  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.repo]

  policy = var.policy_type == "app" ? data.template_file.lifecycle_policy_app.rendered : data.template_file.lifecycle_policy_infra.rendered

}
```

Data template:

```
data "template_file" "lifecycle_policy_app" {

  template = file("lifecyclePolicyApp.json")

  vars = {
    max_untagged_images = var.max_untagged_images
    max_tagged_images = var.max_tagged_images
    env = var.env
  }
}
```

Policy:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rulePriority": 1,
      "description": "Expire untagged images older than ${max_untagged_images} days",
      "selection": {
        "tagStatus": "untagged",
        "countType": "sinceImagePushed",
        "countUnit": "days",
        "countNumber": "${max_untagged_images}"
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    },
    {
      "rulePriority": 2,
      "description": "Expire tagged images of ${env}, older than ${max_tagged_images} days",
      "selection": {
        "tagStatus": "tagged",
        "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
        "countNumber": "${max_tagged_images}",
        "tagPrefixList": [
          "${env}"
        ]
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following 2 steps:

1. Remove the double quotes that around the "${max_tagged_images}"
2. Use terraform function called tonumber in order to convert it to a number:

   tonumber("1")

(Follow the official documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tonumber.html)

Comment: Just removing the quotes is enough.

Comment: Thanks. i tried with the removal of quotes and it works.